# Can't get a While Loop working with my For VBscipt

Tags: vbscript

Hi I'm having trouble with a simple while loop in vbscript.

I've got a Function which splits a string of e-mail addresses based on ";" it then runs each e-mail address through another function (isValidEmail) which does some simple validation checks with a Boolean return.

If any of the "isValidEmail" functions return false I want this "EmailSplitFunc" to return false and exit otherwise I want the whole thing to return true.

I've got the splitting function but I'm struggling to get a While loop in which works. Any ideas?

```
Function EmailSplitFunc(emailaddress)
    Dim EmailSplitArray, i,
    EmailSplitArray = split(EmailStudentCheck,";")
    While isValidEmail(EmailStudentCheck)
    For i = 0 To Ubound(EmailSplitArray)
    EmailStudentCheck = EmailSplitArray(i)
    isValidEmail(EmailStudentCheck)
    Next
    Wend
End function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with top-level code that tests the (to be written) checkMList() function:

```
Option Explicit

Dim aTests : aTests = Array( _
    "a@b.com;nix" _
  , "a@b.com;c@d.com" _
)
Dim sMList
For Each sMList in aTests
    Dim bOk : bOk = checkMList(sMList)
    WScript.Echo CStr(bOk), sMList
Next
```

and add a fake checkM() function:

```
Function checkM(sM)
  checkM = 0 <> InStr(sM, "@")
End Function
```

Then consider checkMList(): It has to split the sMList and check each part for being a valid email; finding the first failure, the function should return False, only if all parts pass the check, True should be returned. This translates to:

```
Function checkMList(sMList)
  Dim sM
  For Each sM In Split(sMList, ";")
      Dim bOk : bOk = checkM(sM)
      WScript.Echo "*", CStr(bOk), sM
      If Not bOk Then
         checkMList = False ' first failure
         Exit Function
      End If
  Next
  checkMList = True ' reached if all ok
End Function
```

output:

```
* True a@b.com
* False nix
False a@b.com;nix
* True a@b.com
* True c@d.com
True a@b.com;c@d.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need one loop..

```
For i = 0 to Ubound(EmailSplitArray)
    If isValidEmail(EmailSplitArray[i]) = False Then
        // Return False 
    End If 
Next
```

Comment: I thought so too but using similar code everything was false. I thought it looked so straightforward at first too.